# Making a box with content, works in HTML not CSS, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, so thought I should ask you guys.

So I have a site, were I have a box with some content: images, text...

This is how it looks in the index.html:

```
    <div id="aust-agder">
    <!-- agent address in the first region -->
    <p style="  background: #111;
                background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
                color: #eee;
                position:absolute;
                z-index:95;
                top:500px;
                left:1050px;
                font: normal 20px 'Lucida Grande',Arial,sans-serif;
                padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
                text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
                -moz-border-radius: 1.6em;
                -ms-border-radius: 1.6em;
                -o-border-radius: 1.6em;
                -webkit-border-radius: 1.6em;
                border-radius: .6em; ">
  Lillesand - Kjøreskole<br>
  Vi vil gratulere A4 Trafikkskole med Digital Skiltløsning<br>
  A4 Trafikkskole<br>
  A: <a href=http://g.co/maps/xybpd>Elvegata 2A, 4608 Kristiansand S</a><br>
  T: 38 02 56 00<br>
  E: <a href=mailto:post@a-4.no>post@a-4.no</a><br>
  Besøk hjemmesiden til <a href=http://www.a-4.no/>A4 Trafikkskole</a><br>

  <img src=images/test.jpg>
    </p>
  </div>
```

When I have this in the html the site looks like this:
http://iseeit.no/maptest/working/

If I remove it from the html and put it in the css file which looks like this if I'm correct:

```
.aust-agder{
    background: #111;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #eee;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:95;
    top:500px;
    left:1050px;
    font: normal 20px 'Lucida Grande',Arial,sans-serif;
    padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 1.6em;
    -ms-border-radius: 1.6em;
    -o-border-radius: 1.6em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1.6em;
    border-radius: .6em; 
}
```

and in the index.html:

```
    <div id="aust-agder">
    <!-- agent address in the first region -->
  Lillesand - Kjøreskole<br>
  Vi vil gratulere A4 Trafikkskole med Digital Skiltløsning<br>
  A4 Trafikkskole<br>
  A: <a href=http://g.co/maps/xybpd>Elvegata 2A, 4608 Kristiansand S</a><br>
  T: 38 02 56 00<br>
  E: <a href=mailto:post@a-4.no>post@a-4.no</a><br>
  Besøk hjemmesiden til <a href=http://www.a-4.no/>A4 Trafikkskole</a><br>

  <img src=images/test.jpg>
    </p>
  </div>
```

The site then looks like this:
http://iseeit.no/maptest/not/

I'm not an expert with css, so I might have been doing it all wrong.

Hope I made the problem clear to you, if not don't hesitate to ask, also sorry for my bad english :)

Also, I can't seem to remove the link colors, with text-decoration: none; any solution for that?

Comment: You need it to be `#aust-agder` instead of `.aust-agder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `#` ,not `.` in your css:

```
#aust-agder{
   background: #111;
   .....
```

`.` is used for styling classes.For styling elements with specific `id`, see this link:  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors

Comment: It worked, just had a little mistake which I also found, but changing the `.` to `#` worked! I can't seem to get the link color to change, I tried this: text-decoration:none can't get that to work though

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are trying to apply css to DIV because you are missing starting tag for `</p>` in index.html. In that case, prefix your css name with "#" instead of "." . It should be like

```
    #aust-agder
    {
        background: #111;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        color: #eee;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:95;
        top:500px;
        left:1050px;
        font: normal 20px 'Lucida Grande',Arial,sans-serif;
        padding: 0.6em 1.2em;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
        -moz-border-radius: 1.6em;
        -ms-border-radius: 1.6em;
        -o-border-radius: 1.6em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1.6em;
        border-radius: .6em; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS you have `.aust-agder` which is a style for the aust-agder **class**. You use an `aust-agder` as **id**, so you need to use `#aust-agder` in your CSS.

See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp) for more information on CSS for ids and classes

Answer (score 1):

aust-agder in your CSS is a class and in your HTML, it's an ID. Use

`#aust-agder` instead of `.aust-agder` or `class="aust-agder"` instead of `id="aust-agder"`